# jQuery UI tabs doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on the page: http://www.turtle-esport.de is the jQuery UI feature "tabs". I use it to switch between 2 "twitch stream channels". I moved that page to another Webspace but now i get this error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
```

The console show me that jQuery is loaded. Can anyone help me?

Comment: May be you are missing jquery-ui library in your code, else add it after including jQuery library

Comment: ty for your request. I added it after Jquery:  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Also other jquery code should be after these two

Comment: Make sure that jqueryUI.js is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistakes

1. Your jQuery file is included after the function call.

[image]

2. Could not find [jQuery UI](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/) included in the page.

So move the code block after the jQuery file. Then download and use the jQuery UI Plugin.